# JSON file in ADF Data Flow is generating with Column Name and "\" symbol

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a below data in csv file.

| ID | userId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 719A070E-4874-E811-9CCE-02152146006A | 123 | Joe |
| 5d7d0a74-f1b9-483a-8e9f-c7f45ccfeda0 | 456 | Mike |

Now, I need to generate below json using Azure Data Factory **Data Flow**,

```
{
    {
        "719A070E-4874-E811-9CCE-02152146006A":{
                 "userId":"123",
                  "Name":"Joe"
             }    
    },
    {
        "5d7d0a74-f1b9-483a-8e9f-c7f45ccfeda0":{
                 "userId":"456",
                  "Name":"Mike"
             }    
    }
 }
```

I have added Data Flow for this and made few transformation. After this transformations, I can able to bring the JSON data into a single column as JSON string. Now I need to generate a file with only that json string data in the derived column 'jsondata'. But that Column name is added as attribute while generating json in sink (with json dataset). How to avoid this?

**Actual Result:**

```
{"jsondata": {{\"719A070E-4874-E811-9CCE-02152146006A\":{
                 \"userId\":\"123\",
                  \"Name\":\"Joe\"
             }    
    },
    {
        \"5d7d0a74-f1b9-483a-8e9f-c7f45ccfeda0\":{
                 \"userId\":\"456\",
                  \"Name\":\"Mike\"
             }    
    }
 }}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
{
    {
        "719A070E-4874-E811-9CCE-02152146006A":{
                 "userId":"123",
                  "Name":"Joe"
             }    
    },
    {
        "5d7d0a74-f1b9-483a-8e9f-c7f45ccfeda0":{
                 "userId":"456",
                  "Name":"Mike"
             }    
    }
 }
```

Column name 'myjson' and escape character \ should not be added into my json output file. *(I tried replace to remove \ but it didn't worked out)*

**Sink Settings:**
[image]
[image]

Below is the Data Preview of SINK. I need to generate json with data in column (jsondata) only. I don't need the header (jsondata) to add as attribute in json file.
[image]

Comment: Can you give the sink dataset settings that you are using for this requirement? Also provide the dataflow JSON if possible

Comment: Sink Settings are added to the original question. Can you please check now.

Comment: If this how your actual data look or the number of columns can vary?

Comment: This is the sample data I formed. based on Original data which has business information and I cannot share here. My ultimate goal is generate file with the data in column. Header of the column should not be added as an attribute in the JSON. Also Not sure how to remove the \ escape character.

Comment: Can you confirm if this is the value of jsondata in the data preview image you have added `{"719A070E-4874-E811-9CCE-02152146006A":{"userId":"123","Name":"Joe"}},{"5d7d0a74-f1b9-483a-8e9f-c7f45ccfeda0":{"userId":"456","Name":"Mike"}}`

Comment: Yes. This is correct.

Comment: Your expected result is not a valid JSON. Check it using this validator: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the column is string type, the output data in not as expected. Since you have the `jsondata` column value as shown below:

```
{
        "719A070E-4874-E811-9CCE-02152146006A":{
                 "userId":"123",
                  "Name":"Joe"
             }    
    },
    {
        "5d7d0a74-f1b9-483a-8e9f-c7f45ccfeda0":{
                 "userId":"456",
                  "Name":"Mike"
             }    
    }
```

[image]

- Ignore the transformations I made in the image. Now concat `[ and ]` to this value to make it a set of objects.

[image]

- Instead of creating a JSON dataset, create a `DelimitedText` dataset with output file name as required with `.json` extension (this would render the output file as JSON even though the dataset in delimited text).

[image]

- Use the sink dataset configurations as shown in the below image (quote character and escape character):

[image]

- This would generate a file which would be rendered as JSON with the following data:

```
[
   {
      "719A070E-4874-E811-9CCE-02152146006A":{
         "userId":"123",
         "Name":"Joe"
      }
   },
   {
      "5d7d0a74-f1b9-483a-8e9f-c7f45ccfeda0":{
         "userId":"456",
         "Name":"Mike"
      }
   }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Once again Thank you Saideep. This worked for me.